# Add top margin/padding to scrollTo offset

Tags: jquery

I'm using [nanoScroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/) for a scrollpane on my site. I'm using the scrollTo method to make sure the current menu item is in view. Problem is, I'd like to add some margin/padding to the top.

Here's the idea: http://glui.me/?i=ztaxq7lveq1gkil/2014-08-05_at_10.22_AM.png/

Here's the default:

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ scrollTo: $('.current_page_item') });
```

I've tried things like this:

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ scrollTo: $('.current_page_item').parent() });
```

or

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ scrollTo: $('.current_page_item').prev() });
```

But they're not dependable. I'd like to do something like:

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ scrollTo: $('.current_page_item') + 100px });
```

I've tried

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ scrollTo: $('.current_page_item').offset({ top: 100 )} });
```

But that doesn't work either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do:

```
var nargin_top = 50;
$(".nano").nanoScroller({ scrollTop: $('.current_page_item').offset().top - nargin_top });
```

you don't really need nanoScroller for that

Comment: That gives me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined.   Which is strange because $('.current_page_item') does exist and should have an offset?